# Could I use a plow solenoid to interrupt my TIG welder with a foot pedal?

Tags: solenoid, high-current

I have a multi-process welder that can do TIG, but only with a lift start and a manually opened and closed gas valve on the torch, with no option for a foot pedal.

I am planning on adding a foot pedal and an arduino to control an argon solenoid for gas flow. I'm wondering if I could use an automotive solenoid in between the torch lead, for two reasons:

1. Primarily, to stop the weld I have to pull the torch away about an inch to break the arc, then come back in to keep the argon over the cooling weld. I'd prefer to be able to lift the pedal to break the arc.
2. Secondarily, the electrode would not be energized when the foot pedal is not depressed.

If I did something like this, would I be damaging the welder at all with the sharp interruption? Is there something better to use for this lead interruption?

The type of product I have in mind is one like [this listing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072MZHK48)

[image: 12V Solenoid]

[image: MP200 Specifications]

Comment: That device is rated for 12V, I strongly suspect that at would arc across its internal contacts; this would reduce the distance you’d need to lift the torch but I don’t think it would extinguish with the torch in place.

Comment: I doubt that the sharp interruption would be a problem, surely the welder is designed so that you can abruptly move the torch away from the workpiece to break the arc?

Comment: Really interesting question +1 .the solenoid will probably weld .

Comment: @Frog the voltage settings on the tig output are 10.8V to 18V, so not really that far off of a vehicle's voltage system. The solenoid will create two air gaps (terminal to plunger, plunger to terminal).

Comment: Simplest option would for sure be to get yourself a proper TIG welder. Modifying it on the low voltage high current side will be costly. What happens if you simply cut the power on the mains side?

Comment: @winny sure, I'd prefer to rig up a foot pedal, arduino, argon valve, and solenoid for my current $700 welder than buy and store a whole other unit. Plus that's not a diy challenge. I'd want the mains power to stay on, so I can continue the next weld with the foot pedal.